# How do I calculate the solid angle of the intersection between a right circular cone and a 'square' cone?

Tags: integration

My basic question is, how do I calculate the solid angle of intersection on the unit sphere between a right circular cone and a 'square' cone, both with bases at the sphere origin (see second diagram below). The details are as follows; sorry for the length but I didn't want you to think I hadn't even tried to do it myself.

An octant of the unit sphere is discretized into panels. Each 'panel' has the same area and thus the solid angle of the 'square' cones are equal (I know they are not square but I couldn't think of a better term). All 4 octants on the upper hemisphere will be used but I have only shown one for simplicity.

[image: Polar/azimuthal discretization]

A right circular cone's axis is defined by a vector $\vec{V}_c(\theta, \phi)$ with apex half angle of $\alpha$, and will intersect with one or more square cones. What I need to calculate, given $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$, $\vec{V}_c$ and $\alpha$, is the solid angle of the conical surface created by the intersection of the circular and square cones (yellow area in figure below).

[image: Intersection between circular and square cones]

I know that the solid angle of a spherical cap (contained within the circular cone) is given by $\Omega = 2\pi(1-\mathrm{cos}(\alpha))$, and that the area of the spherical surface within the square cone can be found by: $$\int_{\phi_1}^{\phi2} \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta2} \ \mathrm{sin}\theta \ d\theta \ d\phi$$

but this does not, of course, help me find the overlap, as the spherical cap equation is based on a cone coincident with the z axis.

I have tried 3 ways of solving this problem (which I will describe below) but my maths skills are very limited and I just can't do it. I am therefore hoping that someone can help.

**Method 1**

I have equations for the intersection of two spherical caps, and so can calculate the overlap between the circular cone and the upper and lower edges of the square. I also have an equation for the area of the spherical cap cut by a plane coincident with the cone apex at an angle $\gamma$ from the cone axis, which can be used to find the overlap on the left and right edges (which are sections of great circles). The problem is that these can't be used if the overlap is a combination of both (i.e. if the overlap is at any of the corners) as I can think of no way to combine the two.

**Method 2**

(From 'Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences' - M L Boas; Pgs. 270-272)

An element of surface area $dA$ is projected onto the $x$, $y$ plane. If $\gamma$ is the acute angle between the tangent plane at $dA$ and the $x$, $y$ plane, then the surface area of a region is given by: $$\iint{dA} = \iint{\mathrm{sec} \gamma \ dx \ dy}$$

and for the unit sphere $\mathrm{sec} \gamma = (1-x^2-y^2)^{-1/2}$.

The problem I face is in defining the limits of integration in $dx$ and $dy$. In the example given in the book, the intersection with the sphere is a cylinder, so the integration is over a simple disk in the $x$, $y$ plane. My projected area of overlap is complicated in that it is composed of two parameterizations (possibly 3, if the $\theta$ and $\phi$ directions are parameterized separately). The square cone is perhaps simple enough, but the circle on the sphere defined by the intersection with the cone is difficult as it will be a function of both $\theta$ and $\phi$. All the examples I found have been simple, where the cone axis is coincident with the z axis, and I have no idea how to derive it for an arbitrarily directed cone. Even if I could derive this, I am not sure how I would use these parameterizations to define the limits of integration.

**Method 3**

(from 'Solid Angle of Conical Surfaces, Polyhedral Cones, and Intersecting Spherical Caps' - Oleg Mazonka; http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1205/1205.1396.pdf)

If I understand it correctly, the following equation can be used to calculate the solid angle of a conical surface defined by a closed parametric curve (see reference for definitions and more info): $$\Omega = 2\pi - \sum_i{\delta_i - ∮ dl \ \sqrt{\vec{u}^2 - (\vec{u} \cdot \vec{s})^2}} $$

My problems with this method are as follows:

Firstly, I am assuming, perhaps incorrectly, that my curve made up of the square and circular cones are parametric curves. As mentioned previously, I don't know how to parameterize the circle on the sphere.

Secondly, I don't know how to perform a line integral on a curve described by more than one parameterization.

The example used in the reference is, again, a simple example using a right circular cone coincident with the z axis.